# TypeError: undefined is not a function in node.js / express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, typeerror

I got the following error: TypeError: undefined is not a function

callback(null, array_reply, threadResults);

this part seems bad but I don't know why.

I need your help. thanks

```
async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        Model.find()
        .limit(10)
        .sort({pushed_date: 'desc'})
        .exec( function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                log('Error: ' + err.message);
                callback(err);
                return;
            }
            var array_reply = new Array();

            async.forEachSeries(results,
            function (result, callback) {
                var reply = result.replies[result.replies_count];
                array_reply.push(reply);
            },callback);
            callback(null, array_reply);
        });
    },
    function (array_reply, callback) {
        Model.find()
        .limit(10)
        .sort( {replies_count: 'desc'} )
        .exec( function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
                return;
            }
            callback(null, array_reply, results);
        });
    }
], function (err, array_reply, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Error!");
        return next(err);
    }
    res.render("aaa.hbs",{
        models: results,
        posts: array_reply
    });
})
```

I changed my source like this.

```
async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        Model.find()
        .limit(10)
        .sort({pushed_date: 'desc'})
        .exec( function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                log('Error: ' + err.message);
                callback(err);
                return;
            }
            var array_reply = new Array();

            async.forEachSeries(results,
            function (result, callback) {
                var reply = result.replies[result.replies_count];
                array_reply.push(reply);
            },callback);
            callback(null, array_reply);
        });
    },
    function (array_reply, callback) {
        Model.find()
        .limit(10)
        .sort( {replies_count: 'desc'} )
        .exec( function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
                return;
            }
           if (results.length > 0) {
                res.render("aaa.hbs",{
                    models: results,
                    posts: array_reply
                });
            } else {
                res.render("aaa.hbs",{
                    models: null,
                    posts: array_reply
                });
            }
        });
    }
], function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Error!");
        return next(err);
    }
})
```

Comment: How is `callback` defined? In this part of code there is no any definition of it.

Comment: I think those callbacks are specification of async. https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall

Answer (score 0):

there is callback double call (may be it causes a problem):

```
async.forEachSeries(results,
        function (result, callback) {
            var reply = result.replies[result.replies_count];
            array_reply.push(reply);
        },callback);
        callback(null, array_reply);
```

I guess it might be as follows:

```
async.forEachSeries(results,
        function (result, callback) {
            var reply = result.replies[result.replies_count];
            array_reply.push(reply);
        },
        function(err) {
           callback(err, array_reply);
        });
```

Comment: thank you Tony. but I think this part is ok. because second one is for back to async.

Comment: Test I am doing right now is case of no data in the DB, so it is only one time. sorry for my English. I am using google translate

Comment: That's ok. So if there is no data, so you will not got to final step, is that right?

Comment: Yes. I made it. I changed my source to not got to final step when no data in mongodb and finally view showed! thank you Tony. (but I am not sure my source is really ok...)

Comment: I edited my code. I don't know my code is ok but errors are gone now.